# How can I use Jinja2 to generate an index-like list?

Tags: sorting, jinja2, pelican

In an index, references are listed alphabetically and grouped by letter. Also, instead of a simple alphabetical sort, leading articles and punctuation are removed before sorting. The result would look like this:

**A**
Abba
The Archer
Away From Here

**B**
"Bangkok" Mike
Bullets

I'm using the Pelican static site generator, which uses Jinja2 in its templates, and I'd like to create an index like this of TV shows that I've blogged about on my site.

TV show names are listed in a metadata field {{ article.showname }} (only one show per post, so only one show in the metadata field) and so are easily retrieved. But stripping the leading article/punctuation, grouping by first letter and inserting the correct letter of the alphabet is more than I know how to do.

### Possible steps I could take

I could strip the leading article/punctuation and create another metadata field with the show name that's ready to be sorted, called, say, {{ article.shownamesort }}. For that matter, if there's not an easy way to group the names by their first letter, I could create a metadata field with the show's first (sortable) letter, {{ article.shownameletter }}.

For each letter, I could create a loop that begins by grabbing that letter's posts:

```
{% if article.shownameletter == "A" %}
```

Once that's done, I don't know how to sort the text from one metadata field based on the text of a different metadata field. That is, I don't know how to print the {{ article.showname }} list that's sorted by the {{ article.shownamesort }} list. Can this be done in Jinja2? For the record, if there's a solution that takes a completely different approach, I'd be very happy with it, including if it required different/more metadata fields.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that on the tags and categories pages. It iterates over all the characters and then prints the results

Iterate over the letters:

```
{% for char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"|list %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comparison for show or not show the tag:

```
{% if char == tag|upper|truncate(1, True, end='') %}
...
{% endif %}
```

**Full example:**

```
{% for char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"|list %}
    <h2>{{char}}</h2>
    {% for tag, articles in tags|sort %}
        {% if char == tag|upper|truncate(1, True, end='') %}
            <dt>{{ tag }}</dt>
            {% for article in articles|sort %}
                <dd><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></dd>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing your code! I'll definitely plug this in and tinker with it. It looks like this will create a list of all tags. I wouldn't want to tag shows with their first letter, since that tag wouldn't be useful to site users. The only tag I want used in this list is the name of the show, which is also printed in the article.showname metadata field. Could I switch the "{% for tag" to look in the article.shownamesort metadata field instead? I consistently get tripped up at that step. Also, I want to link to the show name tag, not list specific articles that reference it.

Comment: Sure you can change the inside for. This is just an example for the **tags** variable.

Comment: Problems: The tag for each show is its full name, like "The Archer." I want the "if char" to look in the article.shownamesort field, which reads "Archer." Changing "if char == tag|" to "if char == article.showsort|" lands me an "'article' is undefined" error.
Also, the goal is to only list the tags which are names of shows (tags that equal article.showname metadata). How can I limit it to that list?

Comment: You may start iterating with the **tags** variable, that is (tag, articles), or iterate **articles** that is a list of articles. Add your code for better understanding.

Comment: Here's what I tried that landed the "'article' is undefined error.
    `{% for tag, articles in tags|sort %}
    {% if char == article.showsort|upper|truncate(1, True, end='') %}`

Comment: That *for*,  gives you a list of articles, another *for* is needed.